# Element´s border are hidden - html2pdf.js

Tags: html, angular, pdf, border, html2pdf

I am using `html2pdf.js` with `Angular 4` to generate a PDF since the HTML file. It works, but there is an issue: when it renders the HTML in PDF borders don't appear.

This is the result in the PDF:
[image]

And this is how my HTML file looks at browser:
[image]

This is how I used html2pdf:

```js
GeneratePDF () {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-body')[1];
    html2pdf(element, {
      margin:       1.5,
      filename:     'myfile.pdf',
      //image:        { type: 'png' },
      html2canvas:  { dpi: 192, letterRendering: true},
      jsPDF:        { unit: 'cm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'p' }
    });
  }
```

I just want to show the border of the tables and the textareas.

Documentation of html2pdf is here: https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf

Comment: If is usefull to somebody, I just do wider the borders, so they appear at PDF.

Comment: We use it in angular 4 too. We use bordered bootstrap tables which have a 1px border only and it works fine. Maybe it got fixed in a recent release?

Comment: I still have this problem, but not using a table